# How to make pygame update the display only upon an event?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to do something like this.

```
pygame.event.set_allowed([pygame.KEYDOWN])
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        . . .
        pygame.display.flip()
```

Since the game I'm making is static when there's no input anyway, I'm trying to avoid re-rendering identical frames between inputs in every single `while True` iteration. This code seems to be *almost* working, except there's the slightest (disorienting) delay between input and result. If someone can help me mitigate this I want to go further and put much of the rest of the code within the `for event in ...` block to optimise a bunch more by skipping iterating over the game state 2D list every loop since it's static until there's input. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way is to update the game in every frame and to limit the frames per second using [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock).

```py
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # handle events
        # [...]

    # clear background
    # [...]

    # draw scene   
    # [...]

    # update the display
    pygame.display.flip()

    # limit frames per second
    clock.tick(100)
```

If there is more than 1 event at once, your approach can update the game several times per frame. Sets a status variable when there was an event and updates the game once when the status is set:

```py
run = True
while run:

    redraw_scene = False
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        redraw_scene = True
 
        # handle events
        # [...]

    if redraw_scene:
        # clear background
        # [...]

        # draw scene
        # [...]

        # update the display
        pygame.display.flip()
```